# How to fetch JSON data stored in DocumentDB JSON file to clientside javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, frontend

I have a website developed using only client side code(JavaScript, Jquery, Html, CSS, Bootstrap). I do not intend to use SQL for now hence I was thinking of using DocumentDB as data related to this website is purely JSON. Currently my website does work without any server side coding but I feel that is not secure way of coding as I believe the JSON data which is currently part of my Javascript file, would be exposed to all once I publish/host website. I have gone through the tutorial of how to create DocumentDB Azure account, how to create database which consists of JSON files. But I do not have definite idea about how to fetch the ***NOW server side JSON data*** using client side Javascript. Right Now all the client side coding part is in Jquery and JavaScript and I am manipulating the JSON data which is in the same .JS file. 
Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not terribly familiar with DocumentDB on Azure, but it seems to support a rest api for crud operations ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/get-a-database)) So easiest method to implement the minimum amount of effort would be to use ajax to GET the information necessary.

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{db-id}',
    headers : {
         //your headers here
    },
    success : function(jsondata){
         //do something
    }
})
```

A thing to note though, it is likely that you will need to hard code the credentials on the front end, if you insist on using only front end technology (as far as DocumentDB is concerned, it seems you need to provide authorisation token in the header [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/common-documentdb-rest-request-headers)). If security is your concern, you might want to do a bit of back end work for querying databases.

On the bright side, if you already know JS, nodejs is a perfect place to start oO.

Comment: thank you for your response and possible solution. I will try this solution. I am new to Ajax and learning it now .

Comment: As I am studying Ajax, I think .getJSON() would be perfect for this scenario. I still am figuring out what to use in place of url.. and which other settings do I need?

Comment: if you have already obtained a documentDB account on azure, you will have a _databaseaccount_ and a _database id_ . 

in addition, you will need an authorisation token (more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/common-documentdb-rest-request-headers and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/access-control-on-documentdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN) However, note that if you hardcode your authorisation token, it's prone to be misused.

Comment: I would recommend use curl or postman, and play around with the rest api, before coding. post man (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) can give you a good visualisation of the request. Better yet, you can generate the ajax request with one click.

Comment: thanks for your response again. Most of these concepts are new to me and I need to do a bit of homework myself. Its kind of overwhelming..

Comment: It's worthwhile getting familiar with postman or curl. You can easily test the restful API, not only of your docmentdb , but also other APIs should you choose to use them.

Comment: Restful API, postman, curl wow! so much stuff to learn. Could you tell me how to get started with learning restful api?

Comment: I think the easiest things to get a handle on are GET and POST requests. Curl and postman are programmes that allow you easily diagnose the said requests (and responses).

Comment: ok. Do you know what is the difference between $(function(){}); and $.function(){};

Comment: And $(//block of code and not just a selctor).SomeFunction(); What is $ exactly? I don't have clear idea. I am trying to collect as much information I can from web. Thanks is advance.

Comment: not too sure about $.function vs $(function(){})... My understanding is $.function access functions whilst $(selector) selects elements. jquery is a javascript library, and dollarsign ($) is a way for jquery to understand that what you are about to type is related to jquery functionalities, to distinguish itself from plain javascript, which (usually) do not start with a dollar sign.

Comment: ok. what I tried is I created a recipes.json file. Earlier the data in this file was part of app.js file. I thought of separating and storing the .json file locally first, and if the solution works out I will transfer the .json file to DocumentDB. what I tried is below. var recipes is the vaiables that I am using in app.js. Since I incorporated this small changes, the data from .json file is not showing up. I tried adding below code with $(function(){}) and with only $.getJSON(), in index.html scrpt section as well as in app.js. Could you see any error in below code?

Comment: $(function(){
          var recipes;
        $.getJSON('Recipes.json', function(data){
                recipes=data;
            });
          });

Comment: Assuming you are doing all these front end (client side) getjson implementation does not accept two variables. It accepts a json obj, with keys such as 'url', 'data', and 'success'. URL field is essential, it takes the form of url : 'https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{db-id}'. You will need to log into your Azure account to find out what your database account and db-id is

Comment: yah, eventually I would have to use the documentDB URL. But as I am still learning, I want to see if its a success if I try to retrieve the json file which is stored in the same folder as index.html file. I have tested the same code with only HTML and .json file and it works. But the above mentioned var recipes is needed for .js code and hence I wanted to assign the object returned by .getJSON to variable recipes which I can then further use for jquery code.